# Login Failed for domain\computername$: not supposed to use at all

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

So, I have recently acquired a new project: meaning I cannot answer any design decisions. I'm supposed to put some finishing touches on this app. Before I get with my BA to discuss time estimations I thought it would be prudent to familiarize myself with some code and walk through some breakpoints to give better estimates for the new release.

The problem? I can't run the app.

I get 
"An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail."

Inner exception is {"Login failed for user 'domain\computername$'."}

This app seems to require being hosted on a local IIS to run locally, so I added the windows feature and enabled windows security. I confirmed to make sure that this is not an intentional part of the design.

```
<add name=name connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
```

Obviously the database I'm pointed at has changed due to the localhost, but still shouldn''t be trying to hit anything with the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated Security should pick up on your Windows identity (ie, your user name).  Check the application pool of the web app.  Under Advanced Settings you can change the identity that the application runs under (normally ApplicationPoolIdentity).  Maybe that is set to your computer name.  That is the only thing that makes even remote sense.

Comment: It is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: Check out "Using the Network Service Account" here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx

Comment: Its helpful in circumventing, but the BA tells me the expected behavior is supposed to be logins based on user name, I can't figure out what may be causing this at all.

Is there anything in the web config i should be looking for?

Comment: I have to admit that I some times give a computer NTFS permissions.  So if the app is trying to write a log file, for example, it will work from the computer for anyone that is logged in.  I would really hope this is not the case but check the web.config Impersonation setting for something besides a user name (<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />)

Comment: There is not one configured